# (NodeJS) Possible to maintain client side index variable to iterate through database element using EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am currently working on a quiz application that pulls questions and answers from a MongoDB instance. The "questions" field in my quiz schema is an array of question objects (contains the question text and associated answers). I am using EJS to display the questions on the client-side as shown below.

**game.ejs snippet**

```
    <div id="question-box" style="display: none">
        <div id="question-box-inner">
            <%- mySet.questions[0].questionText %>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="photo-box" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    
    <div id="start">
        Ready <br> Set <br> Go!
        <div id="liquid"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="answers-box" style="display: none">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <!-- Use a hidden variable to keep track of the index number of the question to go to the next question on buttonclick -->
                <button type="button" id="answer1" class="btn btn-light"> <%- mySet.questions[0].answers[0] %> </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" id="answer2" class="btn btn-light"> <%- mySet.questions[0].answers[1] %> </button>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
                <button type="button" id="answer3" class="btn btn-light"> <%- mySet.questions[0].answers[2] %> </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" id="answer4" class="btn btn-light"> <%- mySet.questions[0].answers[3] %> </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This displays the first question by accessing the 0th index of the questions array. However, instead of just putting 0, I would like to maintain a variable that will increment whenever the user clicks on one of the answer choices i.e. <%- mySet.questions[questionNum].questionText %>. I know that you cannot use variables in HTML so is there a work-around? I tried doing question.innerHTML = <%- mySet.questions[questionNum].questionText %> in my client-side javascript file but this did not run properly. I also thought of, instead of using EJS, maybe I could just bring the whole question set from the server-side onto the client side and then render the questions 1-by-1 using innerHTML. Is this feasible? How do people usually go about displaying server data on the client side without using templating engines? More relevant code is below.

**gameUX.js (client-side)**

```
var questionNum = 1;

const start = document.getElementById("start");
const questionBox = document.getElementById("question-box");
const photoBox = document.getElementById("photo-box");
const answersBox = document.getElementById("answers-box");
const playersBox = document.getElementById("players-box");

const question = document.getElementById("question-box-inner");
const answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
const answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2");
const answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3");
const answer4 = document.getElementById("answer4");

start.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
answer1.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
answer2.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
answer3.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
answer4.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);

function startQuiz() {
    start.style.display = "none";
    questionBox.style.display = "block";
    photoBox.style.display = "block";
    answersBox.style.display = "block";
    playersBox.style.display = "block";
}

function nextQuestion() {
    questionNum += 1
    //do something here
}
```

**game.js (server-side)**

```
module.exports = {
    gameRenderTest: (req, res) => {
        res.render('pages/game.ejs');
    },

    gameRender: (req, res) => {
        var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

        console.log(req.params.tagid);

        var o_id = new ObjectId(req.params.tagid);

        const collection = db.collection('sets');

        collection.find({ _id: o_id }).toArray(function (err, set_list) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(set_list[0].creator);
            res.render('pages/game.ejs', { 'mySet': set_list[0] })
        });
    }
}
```

**set.js (mongoose schema model)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const SetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    descriptionTitle: String,
    description: String,
    photoRef: String,
    questions: [{ questionText: String, answers: [String], correct: Number, qTags: [String] }],
    sTags: [String],
    creator: String,
    upvotes: Number,
    curated: Boolean
    // add ___
});

const Set = module.exports = mongoose.model('Set', SetSchema);
```